# Extract full email code from Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, email-template, css, html

I would need to replicate some emails built-in Marketing Cloud in other tools and I would like to know Which is the best way to extract the full HTML code of an email, considering there are some dynamic content blocks and AMPScript code included on it (assuming that this code will be replaced in the other tool).

Is the 'Show Full HTML' in the editor code view enough or should I send a test email a get the code from there?

Comment: It all depends if you want the final output or if you want the pre-rendered version to replicate the logic of the email in the new tool(s). I believe both can be gathered via API to make retrieval programmatic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this outside of Marketing Cloud to get the fully rendered HTML, for example in Outlook:

In Microsoft Outlook, double-click to open an email. You'll see an “Actions” menu under the “Message” tab. Click on that menu and select the “Other Actions,” then click on “View Source” to see the HTML code.

Source: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/resources/knowledge-base/how-do-i-view-the-html-code-of-an-email/

Or do it in Chrome dev tools. In the email, click the View as a Web Page link. Right-click the page and look at the menu that appears. From that menu, click View page source.

Source: https://www.lifewire.com/view-html-source-in-chrome-3466725

Comment: You need to observe, that a number of test emails should be generated, covering all the options of dynamic content. My best suggestion would be creating a data extension with a number of mock contacts, each having different variations of data, which altogether should cover all the options. Then use the "Based on Subscriber Preview" option under "Content Personalization Options" in Preview and Test. This will send one email based on each record in that data extension, to the address provided in Recipients field of the Preview and Test

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest the best way is,
For each emails,

- Click on *Edit-content*
- Copy the HTML code by clicking on **Code view** [this approach you also get AMPscript codes if any]

Note: However, you may have to recode in other scripting language if you change your ESP.